# Добавить столбец из нескольких файлов в цикле

Tags: python, pandas, циклы, dataframe, merge

У меня есть несколько папок из которых я считываю циклом файлы, создаю в них столбец name и count
Столбец name в каждом файле состоит из части значений из столбца name в ещё одном файле считанным в df. Во всех файлах значения name различны. Мне нужно по этим значениям добавить столбец count из каждого файла в df.

Для примера у меня есть две такие таблицы:

| id | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 48/a | 2 |
| c | 48/c | 5 |

| id | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 50/a | 5 |
| b | 50/b | 6 |
| d | 50/d | 6 |

Нужно получить такую таблицу добавлением из двух предыдущих значения count  в изначальную таблицу df

| name | count |
| --- | --- |
| 48/a | 2 |
| 48/b |  |
| 48/c | 5 |
| 50/a | 5 |
| 50/b | 6 |
| 50/c |  |
| 50/d | 6 |

Код

```
for i in range(len(file)) :
    obj = pd.read_csv(file[i])
    obj['count'] = obj.groupby('id')['id'].transform('count')
    for j in range(obj.shape[0]):
        obj['name'][j] = str(file[i])+'/'+str(obj['id'][j])
    obj.to_csv('frame'+str(i)+'.csv')
    df = df.merge(obj[['name','count']], on = 'link', how = 'outer' )
```

Но мой код мне выдает подобную таблицу:

| name | count_x | count_y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 48/a | 2 |  |
| 48/b |  |  |
| 48/c | 5 |  |
| 50/a |  | 5 |
| 50/b |  | 6 |
| 50/c |  |  |
| 50/d |  | 6 |

Как можно переписать, чтоб все добавлялось в один столбец?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а что мешает установить новый индекс и сделать простую конкатенацию?

```
df1 = df1.set_index("name")
df2 = df2.set_index("name")
res = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

res:

```
     id  count
name          
48/a  a      2
48/c  c      5
50/a  a      5
50/b  b      6
50/d  d      6
```

Ненужные колонки можно убрать, и, если есть желание, сделать reset_index()

**UPDATE**

Если количество колонок может разнится, но нужные вам колонки везде имеют одно и то же имя и значения в колонке `name` уникальны, то можно попробовать так:

```
res1 = pd.merge(res1[['name', 'count']], df2[['name', 'count']], how="outer")
```

res1:

```
   name  count
0  48/a      2
1  48/c      5
2  50/a      5
3  50/b      6
4  50/d      6
```

Comment: Просто я точно не знаю количество изначальных столбцов, они автоматически считываются из разных папок. И мне это нужно добавить к изначальной таблице df, которая содержит множество других данных

Comment: я обновил ответ